# ASP.NET Core list of objects returns "empty" list

Tags: c#, html, .net, api

My mehtod returns an empty list:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetDomoticzDevices")]
    public async Task<List<DomoticzDeviceStatus>> GetAsync() {
        KlevebrandContext dbContext = new KlevebrandContext();
        List<DomoticzDeviceStatus> domoticzDeviceStatuses = new List<DomoticzDeviceStatus>();

        foreach(var domoticzDevice in dbContext.TblDomoticzDevices.ToList())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://10.0.0.11:8080/json.htm?type=devices&rid=" + domoticzDevice.Idx.ToString());

            domoticzDeviceStatuses.Add(new DomoticzDeviceStatus(domoticzDevice, ((JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result))["result"][0]["Data"].ToString(), ((JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result))["result"][0]["LastUpdate"].ToString()));
        }

        return domoticzDeviceStatuses;
    }
```

In my debugger the "domoticzDeviceStatuses" has 15 objects with set values, but in my browser it is empty.

Heres the result in the debugger:

[image]

There are porpper values in the list.

The DomoticzDeviceStatus class looks like this:

```
public class DomoticzDeviceStatus
{
    TblDomoticzDevice _tblDomoticzDevice;
    string _device_status;
    string _timestamp;

    public DomoticzDeviceStatus(TblDomoticzDevice tblDomoticzDevice, string device_status, string timestamp) { 
        _tblDomoticzDevice = tblDomoticzDevice;
        _device_status = device_status;
        _timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

If theres any more information you need just tell me :)

Thanks in advance!
Best regards Max

Comment: Change fields to properties

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change fields in your model to properties.

```
public class DomoticzDeviceStatus
{
    public TblDomoticzDevice TblDomoticzDevice {get; set;}
    public string Device_status {get; set;}
    public string Timestamp {get; set;}

    public DomoticzDeviceStatus(TblDomoticzDevice tblDomoticzDevice, string 
device_status, string timestamp) { 
        TblDomoticzDevice = tblDomoticzDevice;
        Device_status = device_status;
        Timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```